# sending data form HTML input to Rest-Controller and back (Java Spring boot)

Tags: javascript, html, spring-boot, rest, web-applications

I am working on a Simulation to calculate the course of an epidemic. For this I already have my website in which can enter values in the "input" tag which then get sent to the controller. In the controller, the received numbers should get calculated to a result which will send back to the HTML, so it can be shown on the chart on the bottom of the HTML. The problem is sending the numbers between the HTML and the controller especially that way, so it can be shown on the chart (the given x and y values are placeholders).

Does Somebody have a solution and can help me with my problem?

Javascript code simulation with Rest-Controller:

```
package com.example.epidemietest;

import org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication;
import org.springframework.boot.autoconfigure.SpringBootApplication;
import org.springframework.stereotype.Controller;
import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.*;

import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.List;
import java.util.Random;

@SpringBootApplication
@Controller
public class EpidemicSimulation {
    // Define the simulation parameters
    private int population;
    private double infectionRate;
    private double recoveryRate;
    private int days;

    // Define the home endpoint
    @GetMapping("/home")
    public String home() {
        return "index";
    }

    // Define the simulation endpoint
    @PostMapping("/simulation")
    public List<String> runSimulation(

            @RequestParam int population,
            @RequestParam double infectionRate,
            @RequestParam double recoveryRate,
            @RequestParam int days) {

        // Initialize the simulation
        int numInfected = (int) (population * infectionRate);
        int numRecovered = 0;
        int numSusceptible = population - numInfected;

        // Create an empty list to store the results for each day
        List<String> result = new ArrayList<>();

        // Run the simulation for the specified number of days
        for (int day = 1; day <= days; day++) {

            // Calculate the number of people who recover today
            int numRecoveredToday = (int) (numInfected * recoveryRate);

            // Only count people as recovered if they have been infected for more than 7 days
            if (day > 7) {
                numRecovered += numRecoveredToday;
                numInfected -= numRecoveredToday;
            }

            // Calculate the number of people who get infected today
            int numSusceptibleToday = numSusceptible - numInfected - numRecovered;
            Random random = new Random();
            int numInfectedToday = 0;

            // Iterate through each susceptible person and check if they get infected
            for (int i = 0; i < numSusceptibleToday; i++) {
                if (random.nextDouble() < infectionRate) {
                    numInfectedToday++;
                }
            }

            // Update the number of infected and susceptible people
            numInfected += numInfectedToday;
            numSusceptible -= numInfectedToday;

            // Build the result for the current day
            String dayResult = String.format("%d,%d,%d,%d",
                    day, numSusceptible, numInfected, numRecovered);

            // Add the result to the list of results
            result.add(dayResult);
        }

        // Return the list of results
        return result;
    }

    // Define the main method for the application
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        SpringApplication.run(EpidemicSimulation.class, args);
    }
}
```

Html:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
    <title>Simulation-Epidemie</title>

    <!-- Referierte Libaries für individuellen Font -->
    <link rel="preconnect" href="https://fonts.googleapis.com">
    <link rel="preconnect" href="https://fonts.gstatic.com" crossorigin>
    <link href="https://fonts.googleapis.com/css2?family=Open+Sans:ital,wght@0,300;0,400;0,500;0,600;0,700;0,800;1,300;1,400;1,500;1,600;1,700;1,800&display=swap" rel="stylesheet">

    <!-- Link zur CDN für Graphen -->
    <script
            src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/Chart.js/2.9.4/Chart.js">
    </script>

    <!-- CSS für Style der Webseite -->
    <style>

        body {
            font-family: 'Open Sans', sans-serif;
            background-color: gainsboro;
            padding-left: 100px;
            padding-right: 100px;
            text-align: center;
        }
        .header-image {
            width: 100%;
        }
        .headline {
            color: blue;
            text-align: center;
            font-weight: bold;
        }
        .image-container{
            background-color: grey;
            padding: 5px;
        }
        .body-text{
            background-color: lightslategrey;
            width: 1200px;
            margin: auto;
            text-align: center;

        }
        .simulation{
            background-color: lightslategrey;
            width: 1200px;
            margin: auto;
            margin-bottom: 50px;
            text-align: center;

        }
        footer {
            font-family: 'Open Sans', sans-serif;
            text-align: center;
            padding: 3px;
            background-color: lightblue;
            color: black;
            width:100%;
        }
    </style>

</head>
<!-- Body seperiert in verschiedene Container zur besseren Übersicht und Funktionalität -->
<body>
<!-- Banner an der oberen Seite der Webseite -->
<div class="image-container">
    <img class="header-image" src="Banner.png" alt="">
</div>

<!-- Überschrift für den Body -->
<h1 class="headline">
    <br>Simulation einer Epidemie
</h1>

<!-- Text zur Erklärung der Simulation -->
<div class="body-text">
    <br> Die Webseite dient zur Simulation und Einschätzung von Epidemien, bezogen auf einer infektionellen Krankheit wie z.B. Viren.
    <br>
    <br> Bitte geben Sie in den folgenden Feldern die entsprechenden Daten für die Simulation ein.

    <br><br><br>
    <!-- Inputs für die Übergabe der eingegebenen als Post an den Controller -->
    <form id="eingabe" method="post">
        <label for="eingabe">Größe der Population: </label>
        <input type="number" name="population"/> <br/>

        <label for="eingabe">Infektionsrate durch Virus: </label>
        <input type="number" name="infectionRate" step="0.01" min="0" max="1"/> <br/>

        <label for="eingabe">Genesenenschutzrate der Menschen: </label>
        <input type="number" name="recoveryRate" step="0.01" min="0" max="1"/> <br/>

        <label for="eingabe">Zeitraum in Tagen: </label>
        <input type="number" name="days"/> <br/>

        <!-- Submit-Button zur Bestätigung der Eingaben -->
        <button type="submit">Submit</button>
        <br><br><br>



    </form>

</div>

<div style="width:800px; margin:0 auto;" class="Simulation">
    <br><br><br>
    <!-- Canvas-tag zur Initialisierung einer Grafik, in dem Fall des Graphen -->
    <canvas id="graph" style="width:100%;max-width:600px"></canvas>
    <script>
        //Übergebene Daten für die X- und Y-Achse
        var xValues = [50,60,70,80,90,100,110,120,130,140,150];
        var yValues = [7,8,8,9,9,9,10,11,14,14,15];

        //Erstellung eines neuen Graphen
        new Chart("graph", {
            type: "line",
            data: {
                labels: xValues,
                datasets: [{
                    fill: false,
                    lineTension: 0,
                    backgroundColor: "rgba(0,0,255,1.0)",
                    borderColor: "rgba(0,0,255,0.1)",
                    data: yValues
                }]
            },
            //Einstellungen für den Graphen für Titel, Achsen-Titel, Tickrate und Farben
            options: {
                title: {
                    display: true,
                    text: 'Ergebniss Epidemie-Simulation:'
                },
                legend: {display: false, },
                scales: {
                    yAxes: [{ticks: {min: 6, max:16},
                        scaleLabel: {
                            display: true,
                            labelString: 'Infizierte'
                        }}],
                    xAxes: [{
                        scaleLabel: {
                            display: true,
                            labelString: 'Tage'
                        }}]
                }

            }
        });
    </script>
    <br><br><br>

</div>

<footer>
    <p>Entwickler: <br>
        Projekt: Web-Anwendung</p>
</footer>

</body>

</html>
```

[image]

Answer (score 0):

The mechanism to call a controller is a [javascript fetch()](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Fetch_API/Using_Fetch).

You need to change the Submit button type to not be submit and add an onClick handler as follows:

```
<button onclick="callController()">Submit</button>
```

Give each on the form fields an id (in addition to the name):

```
<input id="population" type="number" name="population"/>
```

Then you need to write the js for the `callController()` function triggered by clicking Submit:

```
<script>

    function callController() {

fetch("/simulation?population=" + document.getElementById('population') + "&infectionRate" + document.getElementById('infectionRate') +"&recoveryRate" + document.getElementById('recoveryRate') +"&days" + document.getElementById('days'), {
      method: "POST",
      headers: {
      "Content-Type": "application/json"
               }
      })
  .then((response) => response.json())
  .then((data) => {
                     // data contains your list
                     for(var i = 0; i < data.length; i++) {
                         var splitData = data[i].split(",");
                         // splitData[0] is day, 
                         // splitData[1] is numSusceptible, 
                         // splitData[2] is numInfected, 
                         // splitData[3] is numRecovered

                         // update xValues & yValues
                         // call the Chart render
                         renderChart();
                     }
                 });

    }
</script>
```

The chart rendering js needs to change as follows:

```
<script>
    //Übergebene Daten für die X- und Y-Achse
    var xValues = [50,60,70,80,90,100,110,120,130,140,150];
    var yValues = [7,8,8,9,9,9,10,11,14,14,15];

function renderChart() {
    //Erstellung eines neuen Graphen
    new Chart("graph", {
```

and a } to close off `renderChart()` before

Comment: Thank you very much! For the fetch in the callController function, is that for sending the input or to receive the result from the controller ?

Comment: It sends and receives. The receiving is happening at “then((data) => {“

Comment: I added the code you gave me, but when i submit the data it leads me to a Whitelabel Error Page  (There was an unexpected error (type=Method Not Allowed, status=405).).

Comment: A 405 means that a GET was received when a POST was expected or vice versa. Probably because the fetch with method=POST is not hitting the Controller due to some sort of path problems - you will have to debug using the Chrome Developer Tools (F12 in Windows). Anyway the purpose of stack overflow is to answer specific questions, not to do your project considering your level of knowledge.  I believe that I have done "Does Somebody have a solution and can help me with my problem". I'm out.